# Java JLayeredPane getWidth getHeight

Tags: java, swing

I'm tring to make a simple Card Game in Java using Swing.

So far the problem i've ran into is:
I'm using a JLayeredPane with a null layout to draw cards in layers.

But it seems i can't do getHeight or getWidth of the JLayeredPanel to draw on the layeredPane Bounds.

I tried also to print out the layeredPane.getWidth or layeredPane.getHeight and it prints out zero.

Comment: You may want to override [`getPreferredSize()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) or try a different [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20256794/230513).

Comment: You're likely calling those methods before the layered pane has been rendered, when the sizes *are* in fact 0. The solution is as @trashgod mentions: either try using preferred sizes, or make sure you only get the sizes after rendering, such as within a component listener.

Comment: So i made a little timer that prints out each second.

It indeed is the problem that @Hovercraft Full Of Eels stated,
When i paint my components, the size of the layeredpane is 0.
How should i approach this problem?
How can i be sure to draw the rectangles/images after the window has been rendered?

Comment: I initialized the shapes after the construction of the object, now it shows the size properly.

Need to implement further and ill send feedback, thanks